# Apache NIFI login issue after installation

Tags: apache-nifi, dataflow

I am new to Apache NIFI. I have installed Apache NIFI on my local windows machine. Now, It is asking user's name and password to login. Do you know where I can find or set the password? I did not set any user name and password during installation. I much appreciate the response as soon as possible. Please have a look at the image attachment-> [Nifi login requires a user name and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knhUW.png)

Answer (score 7):

First you go to the "conf/login-identity-providers.xml" file

There if u see something like below

```
  <provider>
        <identifier>single-user-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.SingleUserLoginIdentityProvider</class>
        <property name="Username">3489c555-49b4-4e7d-9e6f-ca7f71abea81</property>
        <property name="Password">25BiJ9913n8q68bPGRxrm0qY6C4Z/GbT</property>
    </provider>
```

Then make username & password property empty like below

```
<provider>
    <identifier>single-user-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.SingleUserLoginIdentityProvider</class>
    <property name="Username"></property>
    <property name="Password"></property>
</provider>
```

Then save the login-identity-providers.xml file and restart the NIFI

After it starts open logs/nifi-app.log file
Then you can able to see generated usename and password like below.

```
Generated Username [3489c734-49b4-4e7d-9e6f-ca7f79abea81]
Generated Password [25BiJ9911n8k68btGRxqm0qY6C4Z/GbT]
```

Use this for login.

Comment: In windows also, run the command nifi.sh single user credentials and DONT forget to restart to get credentials be effected

Comment: This helps, but it's weird, that NiFi itself has not documented this anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: This works; however, for some reason, sometimes this XML entry is regenerated with some random user and password.

Answer (score 3):

As the official GitHub gives

https://github.com/apache/nifi#authenticating

[image: This is the github screenshot]

you can find username and password in .\logs\nifi-app.log use search "password"

and you will see this

[image: nifi-app.log screenshot]

I try change password in windows but failed, but it can be done in Linux.

```
./bin/nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials <username> <password>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just, I am wondering that I can not change the username and password from the cmd (./bin/nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials <username> <password>)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default password using the following (assuming path to nifi is D:\nifi-1.15.0)

```
java -cp d:\nifi-1.15.0\lib\bootstrap\* -Dnifi.properties.file.path=D:\nifi-1.15.0\conf\nifi.properties org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.command.SetSingleUserCredentials username password
```

Comment: The issue is that the script nifi.sh for Linux is more comprehensive than the run-nifi.bat .... that's why i suggest using Linux for Nifi since more control and better environment for a nifi platform .. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Go to `nifi-1.15.2\logs\`,
open `nifi-app.log` and search for `USERNAME`. Copy it and paste it there
[Username and Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzrAq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi
    container_name: nifi
    volumes:
      - /home/my_user/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/conf
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT:8443
      - NIFI_WBE_HTTP_HOST=my_ip
      - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=my_ip:8443
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME:admin
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD:ransom_pwd
    restart: always
```

but the login was not working. So I had to SSH into docker container

then `cd into /opt/nifi/bin and then run ./nifi.ssh set-single-user-credentials username password`

Answer (score 0):

It will have some auto-generated credentials to use by default. You'll see them in the nifi-app.log

```
Generated Username [USERNAME]
Generated Password [PASSWORD]
```