# I can't log in to Apache nifi 1.16.3

Tags: apache-nifi, data-pipeline

I would like to create data pipline with Apach Nifi (for learning purpose) but After installed **jdk-17.0.3.1_windows-x64_bin** and downloaded **Nifi 1.16.3.** to my computer with Win10. I tried to check the generated username and password in **nifi-1.16.3/logs/nifi-app.log** file but it is does not generated, so I cant log in when open **https://localhost:8443/nifi/login** page on my computer. Could anyone get any solution?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876855/apache-nifi-login-issue-after-installation

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reset the username/password as well. Go to your `nifi-1.16.3/bin` and run

`sh nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials <username> <password>`

After that restart your nifi instance.

Ref: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#single_user_identity_provider

Comment: Can I run .sh extension on windows?